# Using Azure Service Bus Queue Auto Forward With ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have 2 Azure Service Bus Queues in the same namespace.  I'm placing scheduled messages using ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc in one of the queues ("scheduled-queue") and messages I want to be processed immediately into the other queue ("now-queue").

What I'd like to do is set the Auto Forward property of the "scheduled-queue" to forward messages to the "now-queue" when the messages hit their ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc.  Will queue forwarding work that way?  Or does queue auto forwarding send both enqueued and not-enqueued messages immediately?

I've been unable to find any documentation or examples anywhere to explain how forwarding handles messages that are currently "invisible" in the queue because they haven't reached enqueue datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forwarding will send all messages from your original queue to the destination queue. If you peek the destination queue, you'll find the message with `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc`, but won't be able to receive it until the it's time will arrive.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how it works.  I wish there was an option to only forward enqueued messages so that I could use the functionality to help separate my scheduled vs non-scheduled messages.  I can easily write a job to move the messages once they enqueue but automatic would have been nice.

Comment: May I ask why are you concerned about future messages to be on a separate queue?

Comment: I wanted to separate future messages so I can manage and process that queue away from my main processing queue.  My main queue is very busy already and I don't know how big my future message queue will grow. So I wanted to segment future from the main queue.  I might also peek in the future queue to see expected future loads.  I can also split the processing if needed for scheduled messages.

Comment: Then perhaps an option would be not to auto-forward on the future-work queue, but have those messages processed and enqueue new items on the current-work in an atomic operation. That way you either dequeue-enqueue, or rollback. It will also allow you to keep the two separated. Just will require to monitor both queues.

Comment: Thanks Sean, that's exactly what I did -- I process the scheduled queue items as they enqueue and then I enqueue them in to the main queue. This was always an option for me, I just wasn't sure if auto-forward could handle it for me but you have made it clear that it would not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve that with a Topic and two subscriptions. I don't have time today to do the repro myself, so let me know if this doesn't work:

Make a topic with two subscriptions. Call one "now" and the other "later". Send messages with a custom property (in Properties) that you call "ScheduledTime" and that you set to the desired datetime you want messages to appear later in "scheduled-queue" (all these names are made up)

When creating the "now" subscription, set it to ForwardTo to the "now-queue" and add a rule, with the CreateSubscription(SubscriptionDescription, RuleDescription) overload if you're using C#, whereby you set the filter to the TrueFilter and set to Action to a SqlRuleAction with teh expression "[REMOVE ScheduledTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-sql-rule-action)" that throws the scheduled time out.

When creating the "later" subscription, set it to ForwardTo to the "scheduled-queue" and add a rule with a TrueFilter and set the Action to a SqlRuleAction that performs "[SET sys.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc=ScheduledTime; REMOVE ScheduledTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-sql-rule-action)"

The rule will copy your value to the desired enqueue time for the target queue before it forwards.

In theory that should all work.

Comment: Clemens, that is an interesting approach and I see how it would probably work.  I think for my needs I'm going to keep it simple and just process the future queue messages and move them to my main work queue as needed.  I have it working and everything is running smoothly.  But I really do like how you've explained using topics, properties, filters and actions to do some message routing.  I'm going to explore what you've described for another part of the system I am building.  Thanks!

Comment: @Clemens, shouldn't the rule on "now" subscription evaluate if ScheduleTime is empty and therefore use SqlFilter? Jeff wanted messages not scheduled to be processed right away.

Comment: I'm just cleaning the property out for "now" if it happens to be there. There's no delay imposed.

Comment: I tried to follow your description @ClemensVasters, but didn't get the expected (messages w/o ScheduleTime to be processed right away and messages with ScheduleTime to get into "now" queue after ScheduleTime-defined time).

Comment: Let me verify this with the engineering team then. This ought to work.